# Starting with the lowest value, print each value in a circular array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this situation:

```
int[] array = new int[] {7, 5, 6}
```

The value of my index i is 1 and it is pointing at the head of my hypothetical circular list. The value "7" at the zero position is the tail.

My aim is to print:

```
5,6,7
```

Do I need a specific structure or can I do it with a simple array?

Comment: Sort the array, and then print each index sequentially.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to Rotate a List in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948202/easiest-way-to-rotate-a-list-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `index = (index + 1) % array.Length;` Something like that.

Answer (score 4):

With a single "for" loop and the modulo operator:

```
int[] array = new int[] {7, 5, 6};

int start = 1;

for (int idx=0; idx<array.Length; idx++)
  Console.Write(array[(idx+start) % array.Length]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing out of the box, but the following will wrap around the array.

```
        int[] array = new int[] { 7, 5, 6 };
        int startPosition = 1;
        string result = "";

        // Run from the start position to the end of the array
        for (int i = startPosition;  i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            result += array[i] + ",";
        }

        // Wrapping around, run from the beginning to the start position
        for (int i = 0; i < startPosition; i++)
        {
            result += array[i] + ",";
        }

        // Output the results
        result = result.TrimEnd(',');
        Console.WriteLine(result);       
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print 5,6,7 you could use:

```
int printIndex = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
     print(print(array[printIndex].ToString());
     printIndex++;
     if(printindex >= array.Length)
          printindex = 0;
}
```